# Javascript array and for loop

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops, for-loop

So I have like 20 pictures that I would like to print out on my page. I guess I should put the images in an array and with only one FOR loop I could just print all of the pictures on the very same page. How could I achieve this? I'm beginner in javascript, not even sure how to put those images in one array, and then fetch each picture's src and then write out them one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: you may want to consider using PHP for this task or - if the images do not change and are not dynamic - do it manually. Using JavaScript for this gives a huge disadavantage to all users who have JavaScript disabled. They will not see the images! But if you need to do so, do it like this:

```
var images = ['img1.jpg', 'img2.jpg', 'img3.jpg', 'img4.jpg', 'img5.jpg'];

for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.setAttribute('src', images[i]);
    img.setAttribute('alt', '');
    document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

Comment: oImg.setAttribute('alt', ''); Might want to change that :)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It's getting to late for me. Edited and corrected it.

Comment: "Using JavaScript for this gives a huge disadavantage to all users who have JavaScript disabled." - Pretty much every site on the internet nowadays uses javascript. If they have it disabled that's their problem. Also, I don't see any real reason why people would disabled JS in the real world.

Comment: True, but there are still some people who will not see the images because you did not want to type out 20 image tags manually. If the image-urls are somehow generated or calculated by JavaScript, then there is a reason to do this, but if the image-tags could just as well be written by hand, why not do it? It is faster and more accessible.

Answer (score 2):

Check out W3C's tutorial, it's great! ;)

Full JavaScript tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/js/
For loop: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp
Array: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_array.asp

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
function E(e){
  return document.getElementById(e);
}
var imgs = ['img1.jpg', 'img2.png', 'img3.jpg', 'img4.jpg', 'img5.png', 'img6.jpg', 'img7.jpg', 'img8.png', 'img9.jpg', 'img10.jpg', 'img11.png', 'img12.jpg', 'img13.jpg', 'img14.png', 'img15.jpg', 'img16.jpg', 'img17.png', 'img18.jpg', 'img19.jpg', 'img20.png'];
var alt = [/*alternative info here like imgs*/];
var ttl = [/*titles here like imgs*/];
var output = '';
for(var i in imgs){
  output += "<img src='"+imgs[i]+"' alt='"+alt[i]+"' title='"+ttl[i]+"' />";
}
E('idWhereYouWantImgs').innerHTML = output;
```

I like to use `.innerHTML`. This is a for in loop. You can use this type of loop in this situation, because an Array is an Object, with numeric indexes. Don't use a for in loop with `.getElementsByName()` or any Element method that should return an Array, in IE 8 or earlier.

Note that the `alt` and `ttl` Arrays must be the same length as the `imgs` Array.